# How to get nested objects and set them to RecyclerView via Retrofit2 in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, android-recyclerview, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a JSON url with nested objects. First class is SubNodes and I can get data from it. It also has an different object that is titled ImageList holds images but I cannot get data from ImageList. I am using RecyclerView. Log returns null. How can I solve this error?

**SubNodes.java**

```
public class SubNodes {
public String body;
public ImageList image;


public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}
}
```

**ImageList.java**

```
public class ImageList {
public String src;

public String getSrc() {
    return src;
}

public void setSrc(String src) {
    this.src = src;
}
}
```

**Retrofit2 codes**

```
requestCatalog.enqueue(new Callback<NewsCatalog>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<NewsCatalog> call, Response<NewsCatalog> response) {
            NewsCatalog catalog = response.body();
            SubNodes subNodes;
            mainNodes = new MainNodes();

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < catalog.nodes.size(); i++) {
                    mainNodes = catalog.nodes.get(i);

                    subNodes = new SubNodes();

                    subNodes.setBody(mainNodes.node.body);
                    Toast.makeText(context,mainNodes.node.image.src,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    subNodes.image.setSrc("bxdbsnd");

                    subNodesList.add(subNodes);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "" + e.getCause());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<NewsCatalog> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

**RecyclerView.Adapter**

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SubNodes subNodes = subNodesList.get(position);

    holder.ivNews.setText(subNodes.image.getSrc());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        holder.tvText.setText(Html.fromHtml(subNodes.getBody(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    } else {
        holder.tvText.setText(Html.fromHtml(subNodes.getBody()));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your sample json? are you able to get the main nodes of your json?

Comment: @SripadRaj yesi I am. Actually I can show them on Log but I cannot set them to TextView. here is my sample JSON.

{
nodes: [
{
node: {
id: "457",
title: "blablabla",
image: {
src: "http://test.muhabirce.de/sites/default/files/styles/teaser/public/images/news/2013/02/k-relief2.jpg?itok=VvbWSOlv",
alt: "",
title: ""
},
body: "blablabla",
category: "blablabla",
created: "blablabla"
}
}

Comment: try putting a setter getter method for your `image` property in your `SubNodes` class and in your view holder change `holder.ivNews.setText(subNodes.image.getSrc());` to `holder.ivNews.setText(subNodes.getImage.getSrc());`. I hope this will work

Comment: I did what you said but again it didn't work :(  any changes in Retrofit codes? I tried many ways but failed. @SripadRaj

Comment: Okay, I solved it doing that.  I added new ImageList variable and identified it on "for" loop. After that, I changed my codes to  imageList.setSrc(mainNodes.node.image.src);
                        subNodes.setImage(imageList);

and it worked. Also big thanks to @SripadRaj

Comment: Cool. Glad you could figure out. :)